# Draggable containing object with globalkey

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a draggable like such (a is a `StatefulWidget`):

```dart
Draggable(child: a, feedback: a, childWhenDragging: null, data: a)
```

However, `a` has a GlobalKey in an effort to preserve state when the widget is dropped. My issue is that when you attempt to drag, a `duplicate GlobalKey` error is thrown (probably because `child` and `feedback` exist on the same frame). Is there any way to achieve this behavior without any errors?

Reproducible example:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class SFWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const SFWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  State<SFWidget> createState() => SFWidgetState();
}

class SFWidgetState extends State<SFWidget> {
  String str = "str";
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(str);
  }

  void edit(String newstr) {
    setState(() {
      str = newstr;
    });
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final key = GlobalKey<SFWidgetState>();
  final widget = SFWidget(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Draggable(
        child: widget,
        feedback: widget,
        data: widget,
        childWhenDragging: null,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you provide the same key on a widget, can you include full sample widget that will reproduce the same issue ? More about [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the same widget stays in the starting place if [`childWhenDragging`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable/childWhenDragging.html) is `null`. From [the official docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Draggable/childWhenDragging.html):

> If `childWhenDragging` is `null`, then the `Draggable` widget will always display child (and so the drag source representation will not change while a drag is underway).

So, to fix it just default the `childWhenDragging` to something that does nothing like `Container()`. Something like below:

```dart
      ...

      body: Draggable(
        child: widget,
        feedback: widget,
        data: widget,
        childWhenDragging: Container(), // <- Here
      ),

      ...
```